# Does confounding always imply endogeneity?

Tags: causality, confounding, endogeneity, omitted-variable-bias

I'm a bit confused with the definitions regarding causal inference. My question is whether we can call measured confounding an endogeneity problem?

Answer (score 2):

I would say no. Confounding *per se* could be endogenous, or it might not be. But if the confounding variable is measured, then it's no longer endogeneity. Here's an example of endogenous confounding:

[image]

Here $U_Y$ is an exogenous variable that we will assume gives rise to the error term for $Y.$ $X$ is confounded with $U_Y,$ which is the definition of endogeneity. Typically, $U_Y$ is not measured. But you could have a similar-looking but quite different situation here:

[image]

Now $Z$ is a measured variable, and is a confounder for the effect of $X$ on $Y,$ the same as before, except that $Z$ is measured. Once the confounding variable is measured, you no longer include it in the error term; and once you no longer include a variable in the error term, it ceases being endogeneity.

Comment: Thank you! I agree with you. I started doubting because sometimes I hear people using confounding and endogeneity terms interchangeably.